# Yadcf date_format not working with Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, yadcf

How can I solve this issue? If I remove bootstrap-datepicker.min.js from the page the Yadcf date_format works fine but I need to keep Bootstrap styling of the date picker?
I tried adding

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#yadcf-filter--sample_7-7').datepicker({
        format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
        autoclose: true
    });
});
```

But it didn't help.

Comment: currently yadcf support jquery date picker only, there is an open issue adding support for another datepicker, so you can open a new issue asking to add support for https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker too